# sqlite output to list among themselves

Tags: sqlite, tcl, eggdrop

how can i show the output to each other? At the moment everything is in a row

```
bind pub "-|-" !sql pub:test:sql
proc pub:test:sql{ nick host handle channel arg } {

set name "%test%"

sqlite3 pre test.db
set result [pre eval {SELECT * FROM pre WHERE rlsname LIKE $name}]
if {$result == ""} {
putnow "PRIVMSG $channel :empty"
} else {
putnow "PRIVMSG #test :result $result"
set id [lindex [split $result] 0]
set outname [lindex [split $result] 1]
set time [lindex [split $result] 2]
putnow "PRIVMSG #test :$outname $time"
}
}
```

at the moment the result looks like this :

```
[09.02.20/21:00:43:243] <testbot> result 4 1.test.1 1581256802 160 2.test.2 1581262727
[09.02.20/21:00:43:243] <testbot> output 1.test.1 1581256802
```

and this is how it should look, among each other :

```
[09.02.20/21:00:43:243] <testbot> result 4 1.test.1 1581256802
[09.02.20/21:00:43:243] <testbot> result 160 2.test.2 1581262727
```

Thank you very much for your help
Regards

Comment: What's the structure of the pre table? how many rows are selected?

Comment: Why not use [`lassign`](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/lassign.htm) instead of all those repeated `set`/`lindex`/`split` lines?

Comment: For `foreach` with multiple variables to accept the elements from that `select`? Though the answer below is generally better for that as it works _with_ the DB engine instead.

Comment: @Jerry Actually a bad idea, since each line has to be prefixed when dealing with IRC, as it ultimately uses a line-oriented protocol.

Answer (score 2):

If you wish to process the selected rows one row at a time, one option is to use optional arguments to the `eval` command to specify a variable name and script. In that form of the `eval` command, each row is assigned to the variable as an array and the script is executed. In your case:

```
per eval {select * from PER ...} per_result {
    puts "$per_result(somecolumn1) $per_result(somecolumn2)"
}
```

or something like that where the array indices are column names.

See the [eval manual page](https://sqlite.org/tclsqlite.html#eval) for more details and examples.